# Positioning replay button at the center at the end of game using CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, replay

I am making a game, which at the end fades the div containing it and gives the user an option to replay.

I wish to place the replay button(which is an image) exactly at the center of faded div. While trying to do so, by showing the replay button which was actually at the center of entire div at the beginning but hidden, it comes and displaces the faded contents of my game.

My question is how can i make the replay button visible without displacing/disturbing other contents

Please comment if i am unclear in my question.

Comment: How about adding an transparent div which has the same position and size with faded div? so you can put the replay button on it.

Comment: How can this be done ? Can u illustrate a bit ?

Comment: see this in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ijse/qyAhH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it finally. I placed the div containing replay button at the end, but not inside the game div, then set the opacity of game div to .2 and them made replay visible and positioned it to right position changing its z-index, margin-left and margin-top etc using javascript.

Comment: A similar implementation here - http://jsfiddle.net/qtPLc/1/ - I see you've solved it. Posting it since i fiddled anyway. :)